upstox access token nodejs
i need code and genrate to access token upstox SDK using node js but i try lot of time but i cant genrate access token read lot of documentation AI also
output give me access token all output
this SDK i wont to be access
url = `https://api.upstox.com/v2/login/authorization/dialog?response_type=code&client_id=${clientId}&redirect_uri=${redirectUri}`;
console.log(url);

let UpstoxClient = require("upstox-js-sdk");

let apiInstance = new UpstoxClient.LoginApi();
let apiVersion = '2.0'
let opts = {
  code: 'aeEqBO',
  clientId: clientId,
  clientSecret: apiSecret,
  redirectUri: redirectUri,
  grantType: 'authorization_code',
};

